# Cross-platform mkdir?

Tags: git, command-line-interface, cross-platform, mkdir

When on Windows, one of the better choices for `mkdir` is to just use Windows' `git` client's built-in `mkdir`.

Cross-platform requirements demand `posix` paths.

Sadly, unlike **any Git other** tool (I have used thus far), using forward slashes leads to the error message:

> The syntax of the command is incorrect.

Googling tells me that Windows Git's `mkdir` requires backward slashes.

Is there any way to fix this? Why does it not accept backward slashes?

If this cannot be fixed, is there another cross-platform `mkdir` alternative (that hopefully does not require any extra installing (on most systems))?

Possible workarounds:

- `cd ... && mkdir x && cd ...`
- Use a programming-language specific solution, e.g. something like:

  ```sh
  node -e \""require('fs').mkdirSync('$1', { recursive: true })"\"
  ```

Still looking for a better alternative though.

Comment: Git doesn't have a built-in mkdir; Git-for-Windows might come with a supplemental one, but that's outside Git proper. That doesn't really help with your issue here though...

Comment: @torek I updated the verbiage - It is a valid point nevertheless :)

Comment: "that hopefully does not require any extra installing" I don't know Windows, but since they don't want to implement POSIX, this is generally impossible, you just have to install extra stuff sonner or later (even if you find a workaround for mkdir, how long until another one pops up?) I'd just use some Node.js tool for it, this one is well known: https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs

Comment: @CiroSantilli新疆棉花TRUMPBANBAD In my case, I am also going with a Node-based solution, since the project requires Node to be installed anyway. Would have preferred a cross-platform solution though. (Maybe I'm just using the Git-Windows `mkdir` wrong etc?) Also FYI: Since v10.12, Node's own [fs.mkdir](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_mkdir_path_options_callback) is sufficient. Shell.js (which has trouble with electron) is not necessary.

Comment: I thought the main point of shelljs was to CLI tools e.g. `mkdir` on top of Node.js calls like `fs.mkdir`, though maybe as you say they also needed to implement their own portability where Node.js lacked. But if it's just one tool, I suppose you could just reimplement a simple CLI version rather than add the dependency.

Comment: (Maybe it would have been better to have a more git specific question along "why doesn't git mkdir work on Windows with backslashes". I'd also do a quick source grep/ping mailing list.)

Comment: @CiroSantilli新疆棉花TRUMPBANBAD I updated the Q to include your suggestion